# How to store data using pouchdb based on category?

Tags: offline, pouchdb

**I need to store data in myapp like userdetails in userdetails category,template data in template.
How can we categorize data in pouch db**

Comment: There's not enough information to provide an answer. What have you tried? Some example data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can have some db

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'

export default () => {
    const db = {
        dbModel: null,
        dbSlider: null,
        dbBook: null,
        dbContent: null,
        dbSession: null,
        dbTip: null,
        dbLecture: null,
        init() {
            this.dbModel = new PouchDB('hedayat_noor');
            this.dbSlider = new PouchDB('slider');
            this.dbBook = new PouchDB('book');
            this.dbContent = new PouchDB('content');
            this.dbSession = new PouchDB('session');
            this.dbTip = new PouchDB('tip');
            this.dbLecture = new PouchDB('lecture');
        },
    };
    db.init();
    Vue.prototype.$db = db
}
```